# Lottery: how does the practice of purchasing multiple combinations affect one's chances?

Tags: probability

Let's say the odds of winning a given lottery are 1 in 5,000,000. If one purchases five different combinations, what are the odds that the person who owns that purchase will win the lottery in question? Are the odds now 1 in 1,000,000 (5,000,000 ÷ 5) or 1 in 4,999,995 (5,000,000 - 5) or some other odds? Intuitively, the answer seems like it ought to be 1 in 1,000,000, but I don't think that's right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are very right to not just trust your intuition, however in this case, it was correct.

If you buy $5$ tickets and there are $5,000,000$ available tickets, then the probability of winning is

$$p = \frac{\text{Number of good outcomes}}{\text{Number of all possible outcomes}} = \frac{5}{5,000,000} = \frac{1}{1,000,000}$$

---

Think about a smaller problem, where there are only $3$ tickets. If you buy one, you have a chance of winning $\frac13$, obviously. Now if you buy $2$, is your chance of winning $\frac12$ (because $2=3-1$) or is it $\frac23$?